# Resubmitting dead letter queue message inside a transaction scope

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, dead-letter

How can I read a message from a dead letter queue and put it back on the parent queue inside a transaction scope given the restriction of only one top level entity being able to participate in a transaction? Ordinarily I'd use a transfer queue to move a message from one queue to another as an atomic operation, but I don't believe DLQ's have transfer queues and even if they did, wouldn't I then have the problem of handling the transfer queues DLQ!

I need to perform this re-submission in a secure way and without the risk of losing the message during the re-submission process.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true you can't resubmit a DLQ message, after a bit of investigation and trial and error, I've found the following works well:

1. Clone the DLQ message using **BrokeredMessage.Clone()**
2. Remove the **DeadLetterReason** and **DeadLetterErrorDescription** entries from **BrokeredMessage.Properties**
3. Inside a **TransactionScope** send the cloned message back to the original queue and complete the DLQ message.

Here is an example:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
   // Create new message
   var resubmittableMessage = originalMessage.Clone();

   // Remove dead letter reason and description
   resubmittableMessage.Properties.Remove("DeadLetterReason");
   resubmittableMessage.Properties.Remove("DeadLetterErrorDescription");

   // Resend cloned DLQ message and complete original DLQ message
   await Task.WhenAll(_messageSender.SendAsync(resubmittableMessage), originalMessage.CompleteAsync());

   // Complete transaction
   scope.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure Service Bus does not allow re-submitting messages. You need to send a new message with corrected data. For the messages found in DLQ, you could defer the original message, submit a copy, and if that was successful, receive and delete the original DLQed message by the sequence number you've received when originally deferred it.

Similar thing is implemented by ServiceBus360 with the [Deferred DLQ feature](https://assist.servicebus360.com/support/solutions/articles/1000251426-release-notes-june-23-2017-latest-).